# Increasing timeout of ReportViewer axd handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer

My application is using a ReportViewer WebControl. I am not using SSRS - just ReportViewer bound to a sql data source.

When I run a very large report, the report will render just fine in the browser, but when I click the toolbar controls to export to PDF or XLS, I get a `Request timed out` error page after ~2 minutes:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Request timed out.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Request timed out.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[HttpException (0x80004005): Request timed out.]
```

I have been investigating this for a while and the best resources I have found are the following 2 pages.

http://www.developmentnow.com/g/115_2005_5_0_0_532058/How-to-set-Report-manager-PDF-export-timeout.htm

[Reporting Services Report Timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840629/reporting-services-report-timeout)

The first link is interesting but there is no actual answer given, and I don't see the Timeout parameter in my query string (see below).

The second doesn't really help either. First of all, I am not using reporting server, and therefore can't set the timeout for individual reports in the way that it describes. Second, I would rather not increase the timeout for the whole application - after all it is there for a reason. I would rather increase it only for `Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd`, since this is the path causing the error - when you export a report to pdf, etc, it opens a direct link to `Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd`. In my case this is:

> `Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?Culture=2057&CultureOverrides=True&UICulture=2057&UICultureOverrides=True&ReportStack=1&ControlID=cf991107384446f8859b148bc815745b&Mode=true&OpType=Export&FileName=InvoicesReport&ContentDisposition=OnlyHtmlInline&Format=PDF`

So I decided to change the executionTimeout for this specific handler in web.config:

> ```
> <location path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd">
>     <system.web>
>       <!-- Set execution timeout to 10 minutes, default is 110 seconds -->
>       <httpRuntime executionTimeout="600"/>
>     </system.web>
>   </location>
> ```

But this gives me "Location element is unused. No project item found at Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd. Path C:\...Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd not fuond".

This makes sense, because Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd doesn't actually exist as a file.

How do I make this work?

**EDIT**

I am using v11 of ReportViewer:

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"
    validate="false" />
</httpHandlers>
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't stated which version of the reportviewer you are using.  Newer versions require an asp.net scriptmanager...

If your version requires a scriptmanager, please try altering the timeout property [AsyncPostBackTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.asyncpostbacktimeout.aspx).

Comment: V11 should be dependant on a scriptmanager, please try altering the asyncpostbacktimeout (default is 90 seconds)

Comment: Hmm. Not sure how this will work. It isn't the control that is causing the problem. It is the axd httphandler url. The export buttons link directly to ReportViewer.axd, and that is what is timing out.

Comment: Your reportviewer control is creating an AsyncPostBack to the resource `ReportViewerWebControl.axd`, this asyncpostback is handled by the scriptmanager.

Comment: Will try and reply with results.

Comment: I added AsyncPostBackTimeout="600" to the ScriptManager. It still timed out - after about 2.5 minutes.

Comment: That's strange... What's the error message that you're getting?

Comment: Try increasing the [executionTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) in your web.config.

Comment: I did, and it worked, as I expected. But I already said in my question that this isn't an ideal solution. I already tried, unsuccessfully, to set executionTimeout for only Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd (see my question). Btw, I think the reason that the the asyncpostbacktimeout suggestion didn't work is that the axd is opened directly (in a new tab). It is a simple GET of the axd httphandler url - ie: not an aspx page and no scriptmanager is involved. So the script manager on the report page isn't involved in generating the pdf and writing it to the response, the httphandler does this.

Comment: You never stated that altering that key worked. You said that you tried to affect `Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd` only and were unsuccessful... (I don't think what you want is possible, you'll have to change that property for your entire site.) If this is unacceptable, create a separate site with just the reportviewer page+control and alter the web.config in that site accordingly) About the asyncpostbackt, you're right you're not timing out because of an asyncpostback but I was only able to figure that out after you posted your error message.

Comment: You're right, I didn't state it. I should have been clearer about exactly what I tried and what worked / didn't work. It was actually the first thing I tried tbh. I guess I'll keep trying to find a better solution.